# zip command throwing error Ubuntu (14.04.5 LTS), Please suggest

Tags: 14.04, command-line, zip, mv

when I am running(zip t3.zip t1.txt) in Ubuntu CLI, its showing error, but generating a random binary file (eg: zin6e9Tx, you can see in 3rd line).

```
 # zip t3.zip t1.txt
      adding: t1.txt (stored 0%)
      zip warning: new zip file left as: zin6e9Tx
      zip I/O error: Function not implemented
      zip error: Could not create output file (was replacing the original zip file)
 #
```

However, when I am opening that binary file. it's showing like below:-

```
   PK^C^D
     ^@^@^@^@^@f<81>ÑP2÷1<8a>^C^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^F^@^\^@t1.txtUT        
     ^@^Cp^Vê^Ä)ê^ux^K^@^A^D^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@t1
      PK^A^B^^^C
    ^@^@^@^@^@f<81>ÑP2÷1<8a>^C^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^F^@^X^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@ 
   
 ´<81>^@^@^@^@t1.txtUT^E^@^Cp^Vê^ux^K^@^A^D^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@PK^E^F^@^@^@^@^A^@^A^@L^@^@^@C^@^@^@^@^@
```

also, unzip is working fine for zin6e9Tx

```
 #unzip zin6e9Tx
      Archive:  zin6e9Tx
      extracting: t1.txt
 #ls
   t1.txt
   zin6e9Tx
```

just FYI mv command is also not working
#mv t1.txt output
mv: cannot move ‘t1.txt’ to ‘output’: Function not implemented

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL or *end-of-life* thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Beyond using a EOL release, your system is likely well behind on upgrade/updates, as 14.04.6 was released 2019-March-7 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/08/ubuntu-14-04-6-lts-released/) so you've not had upgrades since before (*installed systems got updates before the ISO release date*) then if you are correct with 14.04.5 (and can't be using ESM or extended security maintanence)

Comment: Does t3.zip already exist when you  issue the command? Do you get the same behavior when t3.zip doesn't exist? Try -r option with your zip command.

Comment: I tried all. but always getting the same error. mv command is also not working ..error can not move ‘t1.txt’ to ‘output’: Function not implemented

Comment: Your software is *out-of-date* as stated so you may not have any corrections that were available for that release which could be part of the issue; I didn't look nor ask to `apt-cache policy`as I instead stayed on-topic. My first comment (on-topic) link provided an alternate SE site (*Unix & Linux*) where your question would have been on-topic, my comments have directly limited to on-topic subjects for this site (*only hints for you to check out yourself*)